# How can I access JavaScript object key function variable outside scope

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
let boo = {
    'foo' : function() {
        let bar = 94;
    }
}
```

I want to access bar variable outside function scope. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Declare `bar` in the scope that it will be required

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Get your `boo` then call `foo` and find out where the `bar` is located. First you must set `bar` with `this.bar`

Comment: `this.bar = 94;` `(new boo.foo()).bar`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: It is not duplicate of scope of variables, I'm just trying to figure out the way to access bar variable. @addy

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Would you mind If I ask you to  explain what you have done. @JayHarris

Comment: convert boo.foo `toString()` then `eval`. Of course, you need to format the string into something that returns `bar`. That's how you ***CAN*** do it. But I don't really recommend it since that is a bad habit. ***EVAL IS ALWAYS EVIL.***

Answer (score 0):

You can't access it as you have it in your code. That's how closures work by design. If you want to "see inside" the closure, provide some sort of "getter" function.